# is there a way to insert values to a request (Laravel5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request

When I save a post, I want to put the other content as default if the post is empty.

In other words, in the code below, `"$request->content"` is `null`.

```
if (($request->content) == null)
{
    $request->request->add(['content', $request->other_content]);
}
dd($request->content);
```

I've run my code, but the result of `"dd($ request->content)"` is still `null`.
What is wrong?

Thanks in advance your help.

Comment: `$data = $request->all();  if(count($data) == 0) { ... add your content in $data }` and then use $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you add in your request `['content', $request->other_content]` 2 values. but it must be `['content' => $request->other_content]` Try this corrected code

```
if (($request->content) == null) {
    $request->request->add(['content' => $request->other_content]);
}
```

Comment: @QQUINGHELP are you try my post??